# pattern match weird behavior with scala 2.13.4

Tags: scala

I have the following code and my issue is with the DropWhile Function for which the compiler complain and i can't really understand why, especially given the realease notes of scala 2.13.4
https://github.com/scala/scala/releases

```
sealed trait List[+A]
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]
case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

object List {

    @tailrec
    def dropWhile[A](list: List[A], f: A => Boolean): List[A] = list match {
        case Nil => Nil
        case Cons(s, xs) if f(s) => dropWhile(xs, f)
        case Cons(s, xs) if !f(s) => xs
    }

}
```

> On line 35: warning: match may not be exhaustive.
> It would fail on the following input: Cons(_, _)

Is it a bug or limitation or am I not seeing something ?

Comment: `f` isn't a pure function, something may have changed by the time you try to match on the third case, making both the second and third cases fail. Why not just use `Cons(s, xs) =>` for the last one?

Comment: I don't understand how f is not a pure function ? Can you explain ?

Comment: And yes the last case make sense, will try

Comment: It works indeed if i put `case Cons(s, xs) if !f(s) => xs` but still ... i was hoping that the compiler would catch `if f(s)` and `if !(fs)`

Comment: Conditions make it harder (or impossible) to prove that all cases have been covered, I  would simply skip `!f(s)` in second `Cons` case like @user.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Suppose `f` is a mutable `Map`, and another thread also has access to that `Map`. If the other thread does `f(s) = false` first, the second case will fail, and if it again does `f(s) = true` when you try to match the last case, it too will fail. Of course, no one's going to do that with `dropWhile`, but the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: I get your point, but unfortunately I don't see how it applies here. I beleive f: A => Boolean, can not be mutable, and far as i understand FP, this is a pure function type signature. Yes scala is not haskell, and you can side effect anyway, but then we would loose everything about FP reasoning if the compiler makes assumption that every function can have side effect independently of the type signature. But i think i'm going a bit far here. Simply put, why would the compiler make the assumption that f, that is a function, is potentially mutable ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon Why should it make the assumption that it is pure? It's better to be on the safe side (although I don't know if that's why the compiler complains in the first place)

Comment: Nonetheless thanks  for the tip. It helped ^^ and i solved my issue !

Comment: Your assumption that `f` cannot be mutable is false: `var tested = Set.empty[A]; val f: A => Boolean = a => !tested.contains(a).tap(_ => tested = tested + a)`. It should return `true` on first call and `false` on every other. Language has no way of telling whether function is pure or nor.

Comment: I see. Thanks. Well too bad for the FP aspect of Scala here. Reasoning about the code is harder this way

Comment: that's not only limited to functions (and has nothing to do with purity of functions or even mutability), compilers are just incapable (and even if arguing about pure and immutables might be possible to implement but is that really worth the effort ?) of arguing about anything which involves run time determinism. So forget that function, compiler will fail to argue about it even if you used something like `val b = true` and used it in your case clauses `case Cons(s, xs) if b => dropWhile(xs, f)` and `case Cons(s, xs) if !b => xs`

Comment: Understood !!! Thanks for the clarification .

Comment: Just to add to all of the great inputs in the comments, IMO it is clearer to do something like: `case Cons(s, xs) => if (f(s)) { dropWhile(xs, f) } else xs` instead of the 2 cases. It is exhaustive, and non repetitive.

Comment: That’s how I originally wrote it in Haskell actually . The example in my answer was just to match how I did it in scala 

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @user comment on the last guard, and after reviewing the release notes i caught the part that i missed:

```
The following types of matches no longer disable exhaustivity checking:

guards (case <pattern> if <condition> => ...) #9140

.........

New warnings reported can be resolved by:

adding any missing cases
in the case of complementary guards (e.g. if n > 0 and if n <= 0) by dropping the last guard
..........
```

## EDIT1

Based on  @sarveshseri,  @Mateusz Kubuszok further comments above,
This is definitely not a bug, but rather an intrinsic compilers limit.
Doubled checked it in haskell and the warning is exactly the same

```
aDropWhile :: Num a => [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
aDropWhile [] _ = []
aDropWhile (s:xs) f 
  | f s = aDropWhile xs f
  | not (f s) = xs
```

> warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]     Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive     In an equation for ‘aDropWhile’: Patterns not matched: `(_:_) _`

*Note: My haskell is basic*